# Не получается создать JSONParser

Tags: java, android, json

Пытаюсь создать JSONParser следующим кодом:

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
```

на что Eclipse отвечает:

`Multiple markers at this line
    - JSONParser cannot be resolved 
     to a type
    - JSONParser cannot be resolved 
     to a type
    - JSONParser cannot be resolved 
     to a type`

Вот полный код Activity:

```
public class Regictration extends Activity {

private Animation mEnlargeAnimation;
TextView logoReg;
EditText nameReg, familReg, elMailReg, passWordReg;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static String url_registration = "http://sait.ru/reg.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "status";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.regictration);


    String fontPathLogoReg = "fonts/logoreg.ttf";
    logoReg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logoReg);
    Typeface logoRegFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPathLogoReg);
    logoReg.setTypeface(logoRegFont);

    mEnlargeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.drawable.logo_anim);
    logoReg.startAnimation(mEnlargeAnimation);


    nameReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    familReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.famil);
    elMailReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.elMail);
    passWordReg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWord);

    Button btnRegOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReg);

    btnRegOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    logoReg.clearAnimation();
}

class RegNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("Начало регистрации");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String[] args) {
        String name = nameReg.getText().toString();
        String famil = familReg.getText().toString();
        String email = elMailReg.getText().toString();
        String password = passWordReg.getText().toString();

        // Заполняем параметры
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("famil", famil));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // получаем JSON объект
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_registration, "POST", params);

        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        try {
            int status = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (status == 1) {
                // продукт удачно создан
                /*Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // закрываем это окно
                finish();*/
                System.out.println("Зарегистрирован");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        System.out.println("Конец");
    }



}

}
```

Библиотеку в проект добавил. 
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: по всей видимости как то криво добавили библиотеку

Answer (score 1):

В вопросах про JSON *всегда* надо указывать, с какой конкретно JSON-библиотекой вы работаете (или пытаетесь работать), потому что только популярных существует около десятка и в них классы называются похожим образом.

Возможно, вы хотите воспользоваться [org.json.simple](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1/org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser.java#JSONParser) и просто забыли написать `import`. Добавьте

```
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

Возможно, вы подключили [Jackson](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParser.java#JsonParser) или [Gson](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1/com/google/gson/JsonParser.java#JsonParser), тогда вы ошиблись регистром — там `com.google.gson.JsonParser` и `org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser`.

Также возможно, что вы как-то неправильно подключили библиотеку.